# OrmLite multithreading

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to have an access to helper not only from Activities, but, for example, from BroadcastReceivers and AsyncTasks. Am I right, that if I am using OrmLiteBaseActivity to approach it is to use this methods:

```
OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);
OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
```

inside not Activity classes?

**EDIT:**

I understand that helper lifecycle is handled by `OrmLiteBaseActivity`. What I am asking is how to handle helper lifecycle outside of activities. For example, I need an access to database from `BroadcastReceiver` or `AsyncTask`. Is it a right way to achieve this using `OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);`, when I am starting some database stuff in another thread, and `OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();`, when I've done all database work and want to release helper?

Comment: @Gray I've tried to improve my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I right, that if I am using OrmLiteBaseActivity to approach it is to use this methods...

Yes, using the `OpenHelperManager.getHelper(...)` and `releaseHelper()` methods is the right way to do this.  To quote from the [ORMLite Android docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/android):

> If you do not want to extend the OrmLiteBaseActivity and other base classes then you will need to duplicate their functionality. You will need to call `OpenHelperManager.getHelper(Context context, Class openHelperClass)` at the start of your code, save the helper and use it as much as you want, and then call `OpenHelperManager.release()` when you are done with it. You will probably want to have something like the following in your classes:

The sample code in the docs is:

```
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (databaseHelper != null) {
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
        databaseHelper = null;
    }
}

private DBHelper getHelper() {
    if (databaseHelper == null) {
        databaseHelper =
            OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
    return databaseHelper;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but it might be helpful to someone to add that if you are accessing the DB from an AsyncTask, a good place to have the code that goes in onDestroy() could be the onPostExecute.

Comment: I have the same scenario (one activity, multiple DialogFragments, one Service one Widget). Wouldn't it be the easiest way to put the DatabaseHelper to Application? Doing it that way you can access it from everywhere by calling and casting getApplication()...

Comment: @stefan using Application class for managing database is a good idea until a point when you need to close connection. `onTerminate` may not be called and you'll have a leaked opened connection.

Comment: I do this in onTerminate

Comment: But how do you get context in a thread? Maybe it is destroyed , cleared or finished, it may produces some problems if ormlite need to use some method from the context which is not available at the mean time. And because the job is done in that thread(let's say a network call back), so I can't just ignore it and leave. Any ideas?

Comment: First i have to admit ormlite is awesome, But why can`t we put the database connection Release in the on onPause() method. Cause as we know, onDestroy() method is not guaranteed to run. And we may end up with a left open connection!

Comment: Sorry I'm really not an Android expert @NԀƎ.  Can you ask this in the android mailing list or maybe as a github issue?